# Middy, Typescript, and Jest in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, monorepo, lerna, middy

I've set up a Typescript project using Lerna and `yarn workspace`. This project includes an AWS API Gateway API that is backed by several Lambda functions that use Middy for things like CORS and handling timeouts. I prefer to have unit tests for my code, so I wrote tests for these Lambda functions using Jest, and I run them using `ts-jest`. However, when I run the unit tests (the only one I've written so far) for one of my Lambdas, I get the error below.

I've tried adding `"esmoduleInterop": true` (as suggested [here](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/issues/203#issuecomment-395735291)) to the `compilerOptions` section of `tsconfig.json` in the package directory. I tried adding it to the root `tsconfig.json`. I tried a custom `tsconfig.json` for Jest and adding it there. Nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
 FAIL  packages/announcer/test/api/list-non-compliant-rules.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: core_1.default is not a function

       97 | }
       98 |
    >  99 | export const handler = middy(main, {
          |                             ^
      100 |   timeoutEarlyInMillis: TIMEOUT,
      101 |   timeoutEarlyResponse: () => {
      102 |     Log.error(`Timeout of ${TIMEOUT}ms exceeded`)

      at Object.<anonymous> (lambda/api/list-non-compliant-rules.ts:99:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/api/list-non-compliant-rules.test.ts:4:36)
```

I'm importing Middy like so:

```
import middy from "@middy/core"
```

And I'm using it like so:

```
export const handler = middy(main, {
  timeoutEarlyInMillis: TIMEOUT,
  timeoutEarlyResponse: () => {
    Log.error(`Timeout of ${TIMEOUT}ms exceeded`)
    return internalServerError(new Error("Timeout"))
  },
})
  .use(cors())
  .use(httpErrorHandler())
  .use(
    httpContentNegotiation({
      availableLanguages: ["en-US"],
      availableMediaTypes: ["application/vnd.api+json"],
    })
  )
```

Package `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cdk.out"]
}
```

Root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
}
```

Comment: Related to https://github.com/middyjs/middy/issues/850 ?

Comment: Possibly. I'll try the solutions mentioned there and see if they help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the API gateway event not being populated enough.

e.g. Just specifying

```
{
 "headers": {
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
 },
  "body": "{\"ResendEmail\":{\"winId\": \"jr-1234-1234-1234\", \"timestamp\": 1234, \"message\": \"A canned message\"}}"
}
```

Isn't sufficient.

Specify the whole event

```
const defaultEvent: APIGatewayProxyEvent = {
  httpMethod: 'post',
  headers: {Authorization: "dummyToken"},
  body: "dummyBody",
  isBase64Encoded: false,
  path: '/change-expiry-elapsed-days',
  multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
  multiValueHeaders: null,
  pathParameters: null,
  queryStringParameters: null,
  stageVariables: null,
  requestContext: null,
  resource: ''
}

const defaultEvent2: APIGatewayProxyEvent = {
 ...defaultEvent,
 ...mockCall,
};
```

Then call

```
describe('Resend email', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    ddbMock.reset()
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  test('verifies successful response', async () => {
   const result = await main(defaultEvent2, defaultContext) as 
   ResponseTest
   expect(result).toEqual({});
});
```

The context I'm using also has

```
getRemainingTimeInMillis: () => 0,
```

As per

```
const defaultContext: Context = {
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
  functionName: 'test',
  functionVersion: '1',
  invokedFunctionArn: 'arn',
  memoryLimitInMB: '1',
  awsRequestId: 'aws',
  logGroupName: 'log',
  logStreamName: 'stream',
  getRemainingTimeInMillis: () => 0,
  done: () => {
  },
    fail: () => {
  },
    succeed: () => {
  }
}
```

Further, the call does model the input. If the input is json encoded string, then middy will parse 'body' if you apply

```
const defaultEvent: APIGatewayProxyEvent = {
httpMethod: 'post',
headers: {
    authorization: authorizationSample,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({ApproveWinner: apiParamsBasic}),
```

If "Content-Type" is omitted, then the JSON in the body will be passed to the handler function as a string. With Content-Type it will be parsed into JSON.